# Simple Python program to create numeric values based on Unicode values, would like tips to streamline my code

Tags: python

```
print("This program will calculate the numeric value of a name given as input.")

name = input("Please enter your full name: ")
name_list = name.split(' ')
name_list2 = []
for x in name_list:
    y = list(x)
    for x in y:
        name_list2.append(x)

print(name_list2)
num_value = 0

for x in name_list2:
    y = ord(x)
    print("The numeric value of", x, "is", y)
    num_value = num_value + y

print("The numeric value of your name is: ", num_value)
```

Any tips on how to simplify this is appreciated, with my knowledge I couldn't see an easier way to split the list, split out each character (to avoid adding in the whitespace value of 32), and then add them up.

Comment: Or just use `name_list2.extend(y)`. You are basically creating a list of all characters that are not spaces, so `name_list2 = [c for c in name if c != ' ']`. You can do that in the second loop too. Then use `sum()` to produce the sum, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the name and sum the ord's of each character excluding spaces from the count with `if not ch.isspace()`:

```
name = input("Please enter your full name: ")
print("The numeric value of your name is: ", sum(ord(ch) for ch in name if not ch.isspace()))
```

If you want to see each letter use a for loop:

```
name = input("Please enter your full name: ")
sm = 0
for ch in name:
    if not ch.isspace():
        y = ord(ch)
        print("The numeric value of", ch, "is", y)
        sm += y
print("The numeric value of your name is: ", sm)
```